# GCC Macro 1 + 1 not equivilent to 2?

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I was defining registers for working on a Tiva C Series Launchpad using GCC to compile.

In a header file I had code like:

**Sample A**

```
#define GPIOB_BASE 0x40005000
#define GPIOB_AFSEL_R (*((unsigned long *) GPIOB_BASE + 0x420))
#define GPIOB_DEN_R (*((unsigned long *) GPIOB_BASE + 0x51C)) 
#define GPIOB_PCTL_R (*((unsigned long *) GPIOB_BASE + 0x52C))
```

To check that it was doing what I thought it should, I wrote this little program and it returned '10' as expected. I continued on with my project and quickly ran into huge problems with hard faults (writing to unwritable addresses).

**Macro test**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BASE 0x9
#define BASE + PLUS_ONE 0x01

int main(void){
    printf("%d", PLUS_ONE);
}
```

After many hours of pulling my hair out trying to debug, I eventually replaced the addresses with their hard-coded equivalents.

**Sample B**

```
#define GPIOB_BASE 0x40005000
#define GPIOB_AFSEL_R (*((unsigned long *) 0x40005420))
#define GPIOB_DEN_R (*((unsigned long *) 0x4000551C))
#define GPIOB_PCTL_R (*((unsigned long *) 0x4000552C))
```

And the hard faults went away and things started to work!

Can somebody help me understand the difference between *Sample A* and *Sample B*?

(Yes, I should have paid closer attention to the assembly code generated)

Comment: I hope this is a typo: `#define BASE + PLUS_ONE 0x01` and that you mean ``#define PLUS_ONE BASE + 0x01`.

Comment: Yes - your "Macro test" reproduced is nonsense that won't compile even though a complete "working" example, so what chance the rest of the code presented is actually what you ran?

Comment: ALWAYS wrap all macro parameters with ( and ) otherwise you will have just the kinds of problems you mentioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is not done in bytes, it's done in units of the object being pointed at.

In your case, `unsigned long`. So this:

```
 ((unsigned long *) GPIOB_BASE + 0x420
```

will result in the address 0x40005000 + 0x420 * `sizeof (unsigned long)`. Assuming a 32-bit `long`, that'd be 0x40006080 which is clearly not what you want.

You should have written the macros as

```
#define GPIOB_AFSEL_R (*(unsigned long *) (GPIOB_BASE + 0x420))
```

Now the addition happens between the two integers, before the result is cast to a pointer and dereferenced. Much winnier.

Comment: I was thinking that the pre-processor would replace "GPIOB_BASE + 0x420" with a single token - thus restoring the correct order of operations and doing what I expected. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @DanielDevine The preprocessor doesn't do that kind of arithmetic. It can evaluate expressions (in e.g. `#if`) but it won't insert the result into your source.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of `unwind` I would recommend to define registers in a different way.

```
#define GPIOB_BASE 0x40005000
#define GPIOB_REG(offset) (*(unsigned long)(GPIO_BASE + offset))

#define GPIOB_AFSEL_R GPIOB_REG(0x420)
#define GPIOB_DEN_R   GPIOB_REG(0x51C) 
#define GPIOB_PCTL_R  GPIOB_REG(0x52C)
```

This allows to take the values from the datasheet and to forget the pointer arithmetic.